# Sortable HTML table with multirow header

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

There are several JS scripts that can sort HTML table columns, for example this one: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

But they all seem to work if your  (The fixed header rows) is 1 row. I have 3 rows, there are categories at top and breakdown sub categories down, sorta like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Category 1                               | Category 2                         |
| Sub cat 1 | Sub cat 2 | Sub cat 3        | Sub cat 4 | Sub cat 5              |
| data      | data      | data             | data      | data                   |
```

So my question is, is there a script that can sort HTML table rows based on the bottom most thead row.

So in the example I would like to sort the data based on sub cats.

Answer (score 3):

Thumbs up to ajay's answer (not enough reputation to vote directly).  It worked for me. 
 To be a bit more clear about his/her answer in case line numbers change...

Here is line 53 to comment out:

```
if (table.tHead.rows.length != 1) return; // can't cope with two header rows
```

and this is line 78

```
headrow = table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
```

to be replaced by

```
rowsinheader = table.tHead.rows.length;
headrow = table.tHead.rows[rowsinheader-1].cells;   //sort on the last row in header
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout [DataTables](http://datatables.net). It provides advanced table operations, including sorting. It supports sorting by the bottom most thead row natively, see [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html).

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one too, was hoping it would be possible with something as simple as the one I linked with. I don't need any of the fancy features.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation using https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ and I was able to modify the sorttable.js very easily to fix it. Changes made:

1. Line 53: comment out the line.
2. Line 78: replace line 78 with the following two lines:

```
    rowsinheader = table.tHead.rows.length;
    headrow = table.tHead.rows[rowsinheader-1].cells;   //sort on the last row in header
```